# Nested lists in tuple into numpy-array without losing their dimensions

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

How do I turn a tuple of nested lists into a single numpy-array without losing their dimensions?

tuple of nested lists:

```
([[3,4],[3,4]],[[4,5]])
```

resulting numpy-array should be:

```
[[[3,4],[3,4]],[[4,5]]]
```

Comment: You can't turn it into an array because the first sublist has two elements, while the second only one. And if you do `np.array(my_tuple)`, it'll just be an object array of what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [146]: np.array(([[3,4],[3,4]],[[4,5]]))
<ipython-input-146-07d091c86ada>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array(([[3,4],[3,4]],[[4,5]]))
Out[146]: array([list([[3, 4], [3, 4]]), list([[4, 5]])], dtype=object)
```

The result is a single array containing the two lists as given (preserving their dimensions).  What else do you want?